# Replacing substring in a string

Tags: php, string

I am uploading a image file to the server.
Now after uploading the file to the server I need to rename the file with an id, but the extension of the file should be retained.

Eg: if I upload the file image1.png then my server script should retain the extension `.png`. But I need to change the substring to some other substring (primary key of db).

`image1.png` should be renamed to `123.png`
`image2.jpg` should be renamed to `somevalue.jpg`

The image can be of any extension like `.png`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg` etc.

I want to rename then in such a way that the image/file extension should be retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$new_filename = $primary_key . '.' . pathinfo($orig_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot end() function takes arg passed by &reference [thus it can't receive explode() result], so better to use pathinfo() to retrieve the extension (see last edit)

Comment: thans again man:please have a look at my other quetion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482897/geting-a-list-of-all-files-in-a-directory