# Getting a list of all files in a directory

Tags: php, string, file

I want to do following 2 things:

1) Retrieve the list of all files in a directory.

2) and then remove their extensions.

e.g.: If I get a list of files as A.png, B.png, C.jpeg, D.txt,
I want to get A,B,C,D.

How do I do that in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function filename_part($f) {
    return pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
}

$result = array_map("filename_part", scandir($directory));
```

Comment: thanks for answering:But i get error when i copy pasted ur code in a php file.Error is
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare basename() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ccare\store_pic.php on line 7

Comment: uhh .. ok, call it something else .. change in 2 places

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('directory') as $fileInfo) {
        if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    $regex = '/\.\w+/';
    echo preg_replace( $regex, '', $fileInfo->getFilename() ) . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [glob](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function for directory listing, and use this for removing the extension:

```
substr($filename, 0,strrpos($filename,'.')
```